# Power and Divisibility

Tags: number-theory

Find all positive integers $n$ such that $7^n-1$ is divisible by $6^n-1$.

Trying small cases, it seems that there's no such positive integer.

Comment: I think it could help your search if you only include $n$ that is a multiple of $4$.  $6^n$ will always have a $6$ in the units place, so $6^{n}-1$ will always end in $5$ (and be a multiple of $5$).  Powers of $7$ have the units digit of $7, 9, 3, 1$ repeating, the only way you can get a multiple of $5$ here when subtracting $1$ as well is taking the $1$ in the units place (every power of a multiple of $4$).

Comment: Note that, in order to be divisible, it is needed that $(7^n-1)/(6^n-1)\ge 2$ and this implies $n\ge 5$.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments you conclude:

$5|6^n-1 \to 5|7^n-1 \to 4|n$.

So $n=4k$ and we have $36^{2k}-1|7^{4k}-1$.

But $7|36-1$ and so $7|36^{2k}-1$ and so $7|7^{4k}-1$ which is clearly not possible for $k \ge 1$.
So your conjecture was right: There is no such positive $n$.

*Remark*: The key point here was to see why 5 was a good number in the first place. That is, because $5|6-1$. But since this did not get you to a contradiction you may try to apply the same trick again.
So choosing any divisor of $36^2-1=5*7*37$ seems convenient.

And then of course 7 is a better choice than 37 since this will yield a direct contradiction.